# PHP adding values inside multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Please find below the code sample for adding repeated values inside inner array. Can anyone suggest an alternative way to add the values faster? The code will work with smaller arrays, but I want to add big arrays that contain huge amount of data. Also I want to increase execution time.

```
<?php
 $testArry    = array();
 $testArry[0] = array(
     "text" => "AB",
     "count" => 2
 );
 $testArry[1] = array(
     "text" => "AB",
     "count" => 5
 );
 $testArry[2] = array(
     "text" => "BC",
     "count" => 1
 );
 $testArry[3] = array(
     "text" => "BD",
     "count" => 1
 );
 $testArry[4] = array(
     "text" => "BC",
     "count" => 7
 );
 $testArry[5] = array(
     "text" => "AB",
     "count" => 6
 );
 $testArry[6] = array(
     "text" => "AB",
     "count" => 2
 );
 $testArry[7] = array(
     "text" => "BD",
     "count" => 111
 );
 $match_key   = array();
 $final       = array();
 foreach ($testArry as $current_key => $current_array) {
$match_key = array();

foreach ($testArry as $search_key => $search_array) {
    $key = '';
    if ($search_array['text'] == $current_array['text']) {

        $match_key[] = $search_key;

        $key = $search_array['text'];
        if (isset($final[$key])) {
            $final[$key] += $search_array['count'];
        } else {

            $final[$key] = $search_array['count'];
        }
    }
}

for ($j = 0; $j < count($match_key); $j++) {

    unset($testArry[$match_key[$j]]);
}
 }
      print_r($final);
 ?>
```

Anyway to add memory during the execution time?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your expected output

Comment: You research array_search() and array_column() functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One array_walk will be enough to solve your problem,

```
$final = [];
 array_walk($testArry, function($item) use(&$final){
     $final[$item['text']] = (!empty($final[$item['text']]) ? $final[$item['text']] : 0) + $item['count']; 
 });
 print_r($final);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [AB] => 15
    [BC] => 8
    [BD] => 112
)
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a8885f6f1ce23710db6436c91e5ccca27fb220b1)

[array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) — Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array

Answer (score 0):

> **[array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) - Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays**
>
> **[array_key_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) - Checks if the given key or index exists in the array**

You can use **`array_walk`** and **`array_key_exists`** to iterate through the array element and sum the one which has text index same

```
$res = [];
array_map(function($v) use (&$res){
  array_key_exists($v['text'], $res) ? ($res[$v['text']] += $v['count']) : ($res[$v['text']] = $v['count']);
}, $testArry);
```